# Count the sequences of a factor

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
Date         Event
2018-06-01   A
2018-06-02   A
2018-06-02   B
2018-06-03   B
2018-06-04   B
2018-06-04   B
2018-06-05   A
```

And I would like to extract the sequence where the same event occurs several times in a row. So for instance in the example shown above this would give me this :

```
Event  Sequence
A      2
B      4
A      1
```

I tried to use `rle` but I'm running into problems because `df$Event` isn't an atomic vector.

Since I only have two types of event, I thought what I could do was replace `A` with `1` and `B` with `2` and then use `as.numeric` on `df$Event` so that I can use `rle`. However, this doesn't seem very practical in the long term, what would be another, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: If it's a factor, just use `rle(as.character(df$Event))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I imagine `as.integer` will be faster

Comment: @MichaelChirico, I doubt that this will be a bottleneck; and the result will be more informative if you have the descriptive labels instead of integer-representation of levels.

Comment: @docendodiscimus this works thanks ! Since your answer is a comment I can't accept it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your "Event" column is a factor-variable, you can simply turn it into a character variable and run `rle` on it:

```
rle(as.character(df$Event))

#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:3] 2 4 1
#  values : chr [1:3] "A" "B" "A"
```

If you want to create the data.frame you showed in your question, you can do this using

```
with(rle(as.character(df$Event)), data.frame(Event=values, Sequence=lengths))

#  Event Sequence
#1     A        2
#2     B        4
#3     A        1
```

Answer (score 0):

as commented, it is just a question to set your variable to character to use rle. I give here just two other methods, using dplyr or data.table

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(rleid(Event)) %>%
  summarise(Sequence =n(),event = Event[1])

df <- setDT(df)
df[,.(Sequence =.N,event = Event)[1],by = rleid(Event)]

  `rleid(Event)` Sequence  event
           <int>    <int> <fctr>
1              1        2      A
2              2        4      B
3              3        1      A
```